# How to go to my new Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I'm testing out writing mobile web app that connects to Facebook.
I follow this guide here and created a app on facebook, and uploaded the code to my own server.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/

But then, I got to the point where it tells me to search for my own app in facebook.com. My app won't show up, and I found out they won't until you have some users and then it'll be indexed.
So how do I get to my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have your app settings (on the advanced screen: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/advanced) set to either sandbox mode enabled or Social discover disabled.